# Eigenvalues of a non square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm confused about the existance of eigenvectors for linear functions like this one.

Consider a vector space such that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ where every vector $\vec{x}$ can be written as $\vec{x}=\vec{x_1}+\vec{x_2}$ where $\vec{x_1} \in W_1$ and $\vec{x_2} \in W_2$

Then consider the linear function $p:V\rightarrow W_1$ such that $p(\vec{x})=\vec{x_1}$

Should the vectors of $W_1$ be considered eigenvectors with eigenvalues $1$? (And the vectors of $W_2$ eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0$?)

I mean the domain and codomain of the function are not the same space (I'm supposing $dim(W_1)<dim(W)$) and the matrix of the function is not a square matrix, but still if $\vec{v} \in W_1$ then $p(\vec{v})=\vec{v}$

Eigenvectors are defined just for endomorphisms (and so for square matrices), aren't they?

Am I missing something important?

Thanks in advice for your help

Comment: You're right, they're defined only for endomorphisms.

Comment: But $W_1$ is canonically isomorphic to the subspace $W_1\oplus0$ of $V$, and so $p$ can be viewed as an endomorphism of $V$.

Answer (score 2):

To talk about the eigenvalues of a projection, you want the codomain to be also equal to $V$. That is, you consider the same map $p$ but with the codomain taken to be $V$.

In that case, $p \colon V \rightarrow V$ is an endomorphism, the subspace $W_1 = \mathrm{im}(p)$ is the eigenspace of $p$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ and the subspace $W_2 = \mathrm{ker}(p)$ is the eigenspace of $p$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$.